# How to print a n-dimensional c++ STL container? Container is array of arrays or vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I have a code where I want to display tensor represented as vectors of vectors or std::arrays of std::arrays. The intention is to print them the way numpy prints them. I am still learning meta programming in c++ and wanted to explore how to print the n-dim container using function template that can take this container of containers and iterate through it recursively and return a string which I can later cout.

Numpy example:

```
>>> np.ones([2,2])
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
>>> np.ones([2,2,4])
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
>>> np.ones(4)
array([1., 1., 1., 1.])
>>>
```

**Tried so far**:
I tried the response accepted here as the response:

[Print simply STL vectors of vectors recursively in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594043/print-simply-stl-vectors-of-vectors-recursively-in-c)

It did work for me for 2 dim vectors but the compilation failed for me with 3d vectors when I changed the call to `printContainer()` to `printContainerV2()` inside `printContainerV2()`:

**Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iter, typename Cont>
bool isLast(Iter iter, const Cont& cont)
{
    return (iter != cont.end()) && (next(iter) == cont.end());
}


template <typename T>
struct is_cont {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T,typename Alloc>
struct is_cont<std::vector<T,Alloc> > {
    static const bool value = true;
};


template <typename T>
std::string printContainer(T const& container)
{
    std::string str = "{";
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); ++ it)
        if (isLast(it, container))
                str = str + std::to_string(*it) + "}";
        else
                str = str + std::to_string(*it) + ",";
    return str;
}

template<typename T>
using if_not_cont = std::enable_if<!is_cont<T>::value, T>;

template<typename T>
using if_cont = std::enable_if<is_cont<T>::value, T>;

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_cont<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
std::string printContainerV2(T const& container)
{
    std::string str = "{";
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); ++ it)
        if (isLast(it, container))
                str = str + std::to_string(*it) + "}";
        else
                str = str + std::to_string(*it) + ",";
    return str;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_cont<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
std::string printContainerV2(T const& container)
{
    std::string str = "{";
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); ++ it)
        if (isLast(it, container))
                str = str + printContainerV2(*it) + "}";
        else
                str = str + printContainerV2(*it) + ",";
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A({2,3,6,8});
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> M(2,A);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> m3{{{1,2}, {3,4}},{{5,6}, {7,8}},{{1,2}, {5,9}}};

    std::cout << is_cont<decltype(A)>::value << std::endl;  // returns true !

    // for (auto it = std::begin(M); it != std::end(M); ++ it)
    // {
    //     std::cout << printContainer(*it) << std::endl; // works well std::vector<int>
    //     std::cout << is_cont<decltype(*it)>::value << std::endl; // return false :(
    // }

    // Want to use this for printing a std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::cout << printContainerV2(M) << std::endl; // not working !
    std::cout << printContainerV2(m3) << std::endl; // not working
}
```

**Command**: `clang++ --std=c++17 test.cpp`
test.cpp is the name of the code above.

**I got this error**:

```
test.cpp:45:20: error: no matching function for call to 'begin'
    for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); ++ it)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:59:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'printContainerV2<int, nullptr>'
      requested here
                str = str + printContainerV2(*it) + "}";
                            ^
test.cpp:59:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'printContainerV2<std::__1::vector<int,
      std::__1::allocator<int> >, nullptr>' requested here
test.cpp:80:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'printContainerV2<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >, nullptr>' requested here
     std::cout << printContainerV2(M) << std::endl; // not working !
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/initializer_list:99:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'initializer_list<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'int'
begin(initializer_list<_Ep> __il) _NOEXCEPT
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1753:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match '_Tp [_Np]' against 'const int'
begin(_Tp (&__array)[_Np])
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1771:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Cp = const int]: member reference base type
      'const int' is not a structure or union
begin(_Cp& __c) -> decltype(__c.begin())
^                              ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1779:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Cp = int]: member reference base type 'const int' is
      not a structure or union
begin(const _Cp& __c) -> decltype(__c.begin())
^                                    ~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: If you look at your first error, `"error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const int&)’"`, your recursive end-condition has failed and you have recursed one-level too deep and are attempting to get an iterator for an `int` reference. `std::begin(int)` has no meaning, thus the error. Go back through your recursion and include a test that stops recursion and returns where the thing you try to create an iterator for fails.

Comment: Notice that empty container have missing `"}"` (that printing which should be outside of the loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your first `printContainerV2` is enabled, `!is_cont<T>::value` is `true`, which means that your `T` is no longer a `container` type at this time. In your example, they are `int`, so you cannot call `std::begin` on the `int`, you should directly return `std::to_string(value)`.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_cont<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
std::string printContainerV2(T const& value)
{
    return std::to_string(value);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/nxbYKseov)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to print vectors of any dimension:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T> &vec){
    out << "[ ";
    for(const auto& t: vec){
        out << t << " ";
    }
    out << "] ";
    return out;
}
```

For any other container, you can do the exact same thing.

Use:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v_ds
        {
            {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8},{9,10}}, {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8},{9,10}}}
        };
    std::cout << v_ds << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is a version of operator<< that can print anything that can be iterated over (such as std::array, std::vector, std::list, and even c-arrays of known bounds):

```
template<typename Container, typename = 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::void_t<
        decltype(static_cast<typename Container::const_iterator (*)(const Container&)>(&std::cbegin)),
        decltype(static_cast<typename Container::const_iterator (*)(const Container&)>(&std::cend))>, void>
        && !std::is_same_v<std::string, Container>>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container &vec)
{
    out << "[ ";
    for(const auto& t: vec){
        out << t << " ";
    }
    out << "] ";
    return out;
}
```

Messy, I know, but is such syntactic sugar to use :)

**ANOTHER EDIT:** The version I posted before was subtly wrong when working with c-arrays. Here is an updated version:

```
template<class...> constexpr bool true_t = true; // replacement of void_t

template<typename Container>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, Container&& vec) -> 
    std::enable_if_t<
        true_t<
            decltype(std::cbegin(vec)),
            decltype(std::cend(vec))
        >
        && !std::is_convertible_v<Container, std::string_view>,
        std::ostream&
    >
{
    out << "[ ";
    for(const auto& t: vec){
        out << t << " ";
    }
    out << "] ";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: If you mix containers, it is important to have all declarations of functions before the implementation (ADL would only found namespace `std` and the ones from `T`).

Comment: It misses the comma separator moreover ;-)

Comment: Can we write one function template that takes either vector or array?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I was too lazy to add that :). It could, however, easily be added.

Comment: @patro will add a template with that functionality.

Comment: @patro added that. Uses messy function template magic :)

Comment: I marked the SFINAE response as the answer as that was what I was trying to debug. Thanks though!

Comment: @patro Okay. I did use SFINAE though, with enable_if

Answer (score 2):

For nested containers in C++17, differentiating types, you could do something like:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template <typename, typename = void> constexpr bool is_iterable{};
template <> constexpr bool is_iterable<string> = false;
template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr bool is_iterable<T[N]> = true;
template <typename T> constexpr bool is_iterable<T, void_t<decltype(declval<T>().begin()), decltype(declval<T>().end())>> = true;

template <typename> constexpr bool is_set{};
template <typename T> constexpr bool is_set<set<T>> = true;
template <typename T, typename U> constexpr bool is_set<map<T, U>> = true;

template <typename> constexpr bool is_tuple{};
template <typename... T> constexpr bool is_tuple<tuple<T...>> = true;
template <typename T, typename U> constexpr bool is_tuple<pair<T, U>> = true;

inline string to_string(string s) { return '"' + s + '"'; }
inline string to_string(char c) { return '\'' + string(1, c) + '\''; }

template<typename T>
string print(const T& t, string&& s = string(), size_t depth = 0) {
    constexpr size_t TAB_SPACES = 2;
    if constexpr (!is_tuple<T> and !is_iterable<T>) {
        if (s.back() == '\n') s.pop_back();
        s += to_string(t) + ", ";
    } else {
        pair<string, string> braces = is_tuple<T> ? pair("(", ")") : is_set<T> ? pair("{", "}") : pair("[", "]");
        s += string(TAB_SPACES * depth, ' ') + braces.first + '\n';
        if constexpr (is_tuple<T>)
            if constexpr (tuple_size_v<T> == 0) s.push_back('\0');
            else apply([&s, depth](const auto&... x){ ((s = print(x, move(s), depth + 1)), ...); }, t);
        else if (begin(t) == end(t)) s.push_back('\0');
        else for_each(begin(t), end(t), [&s, depth](const auto& x){ s = print(x, move(s), depth + 1); });
        s.erase(s.length() - 2);
        if (s.back() == ')' or s.back() == '}' or s.back() == ']') s += '\n' + string(TAB_SPACES * depth, ' ');
        s += braces.second + ",\n";
    }
    if (depth == 0) cout << s.erase(s.length() - 2) << endl;
    return move(s);
}
```

Then:

```cpp
vector<map<int, string>> ex = {{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}}};
print(ex);
```

Will print:

```
[
  {
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b")
  }
]
```

Used for a scripting template where simplicity and no external deps took priority. Production probably better served by a library.